# Why BigQuery AutoDetection does not detect my schema?

Tags: google-bigquery

In order to test my component, I have to load a file to BigQuery without knowing its structure.
I used autodetect in BigQuery and it worked fine.
Later, I had to hash the fields in my test file and I loaded it again in BigQuery.

What I can't explain is that the file is loaded differently.

When my fields are not hashed:
[table loaded without hashed fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GecGF.png)

When my fields are hashed:
[table loaded with hashed fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esHSS.png)

Could someone explain what happens please ?

Answer (score 0):

Schema auto-detection can be used with CSV, JSON, and Sheets external data sources. When schema auto-detection is enabled, BigQuery makes a best-effort attempt to automatically infer the schema from the source data

BigQuery detects the following delimiters:

comma ( , )

pipe ( | )

tab ( \t )

There might be possibility,that your hash value is containing any delimiter which is leading to the failure of auto detect schema feature of bigquery

If BigQuery doesn't recognize the format, Auto detect might not work properly . In that case, you might need to preprocess the source data before loading it.

Reference:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schema-detect#auto-detection_details

Comment: My delimiter is a comma so no problem for the delimiter.
As shown in the pictures, there is no comma in my hashes so I guess the auto detect might not work properly indeed.

Comment: Then Possibly Bigquery doesn't recognize format and hence unable to autodetect